# Why is the counter variable not being decremented?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to wait till all the call back are completed. However, the counter is not being decremented. How do I fix this?

```
var counter = json.length;

for(i=0;i<json.length;i++){
    FB.api("url",function(response){
        doSomething(response);
        counter = counter - 1;
    });
}

while(counter>0){
    alert(counter);
}
```

In the above code the counter value is staying the same as json.length.

Comment: How is foo.api implemented? If it returns a promise you could look at using something like Promise.all.

Comment: asynchronous code strikes again.

Comment: I updated the code. I'm using Facebook graph api. It takes in a callback function.

Comment: Is there any error after `FB.api` returns, like in `doSomething(response)`?

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot the code works fine - no errors returned. It is because of the call back function the counter value is not being reduced. Code is stuck at an infinite loop at the while section.

Comment: Here's the issue ... you never let FB.api run, because of your synchronous while loop hogging all the resources

Comment: I suspect you want to "wait" until all the requests have completed before continuing on ... you need to know how to deal with asynchronous code

Comment: @JaromandaX wow nice catch. didn't think about it at all. Is there a way for me to wait till the fb api runs? Please post this as an answer. I'll accept it.

Comment: @user3587180 possible using recursive, function calling itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait until all jQuery Ajax requests are done?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709597/wait-until-all-jquery-ajax-requests-are-done)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the issue ... you never let FB.api run, because of your synchronous while loop hogging all the resources

A simplistic approach would be as follows

```
var counter = json.length;

for (i=0;i<json.length;i++){
    FB.api("url",function(response){
        doSomething(response);
        counter = counter - 1;
        if(counter == 0) {
            allDone();
        }
    });
}
```

where allDone is a function to run once all FB.api have completed

A modern approach would probably use Promises - perhaps like this

```
Promise.all(json.map(function(item) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        FB.api("url",function(response){
            doSomething(response);
            resolve(response);
        });
    });
})).then(function(results) {
    // all done at this point, results is an array of responses from above
});
```

Or, as @Bergi pointed out

```
Promise.all(json.map(item => 
    new Promise(resolve => 
        FB.api("url", resolve)
    )
    .then(doSomething)
))
.then(function(results) {
    // all done at this point, results is an array of responses from above
});
```

(ES5 version here)

```
Promise.all(json.map(function(item) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        FB.api("url", resolve);
    }).then(doSomething);
})).then(function(results) {
    // all done at this point, results is an array of responses from above
});
```

This assumes, however, that the callback in `FB.api` only ever gets a single argument - i.e. what to do in the case of an error?

Comment: `return new Promise(resolve => { FB.api("url", resolve) }).then(doSomething)`

Comment: yeah, that too @Bergi :p I thought perhaps the `FB.api` call in the question was "simplified", there doesn't seem to be any error checking done in the question - your cleaner solution may not be appropriate (I just don't know `FB.api` well enough to make a judgement call)

Answer (score -3):

```
var counter = json.length;

for(i=0;i<json.length;i++){
    FB.api("url",function(response){
        doSomething(response);
        counter = counter - 1;
        while(counter>0){
                Alert (counter)
         }
    });
}
```

Comment: no ... you end up with a synchronous loop that hogs all the resources anyway

Comment: You should post an explanation along with your code snippet.